# getting a stack overflow exception in this socket async receive method

Tags: c#, sockets, udp

I have a customer that reports a stack overflow exception in this method below (on a UDP socket). The documentation says that Socket.RecieveFromAsync can return synchronously, but I cannot figure out how to make it do that in a unit test. How do I force that method to return synchronously for testing purposes?

```
private void OnReceive(object sender, SocketAsyncEventArgs e)
{
    if (e != null)
    {
        var length = e.BytesTransferred;
        if (length > 0)
        {
            FireBytesReceivedFrom(datagram, length, (IPEndPoint) e.RemoteEndPoint);
        }
        e.Dispose();
    }
    var s = _socket;
    if (s != null)
    {
        var args = new SocketAsyncEventArgs();
        try
        {
            args.RemoteEndPoint = _remoteEndPoint;
            args.SetBuffer(datagram, 0, datagram.Length);
            args.Completed += OnReceive;
            if (!s.ReceiveFromAsync(args))
                OnReceive(this, args); // stack overflow occurs here
        }
        catch (ObjectDisposedException)
        {
            // this is expected after a disconnect
            args.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't actually understand why you have that line of code anyway. You are effectively creating a recursive loop that will only be broken once the task completes. Seems like a race to get the task to complete before you overflow the stack, and it isn't always winning!

Comment: This method is expected to receive data until the socket is closed. It's not made to reach a "complete" state. And I can remove the recursive call by using a GOTO call. However, I wanted a test that reproduced the problem first.